# Insert one multiline txt file into another line by line

Tags: python

I have two multiline txt files.
File1 :

```
- one 
- two 
- three
```

File2 :

```
- uno
- dos
- tres
```

I would like to create a merged file that looks like this :

```
- one
 - uno
- two
 - dos
- three
 - tres
```

So far I have only found one solution that can do this:

```
import itertools
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:

# Merge data:
w1 = [line.strip() for line in f1]
w2 = [line.strip() for line in f2]
iters = [iter(w1), iter(w2)]
result = list(it.next() for it in itertools.cycle(iters))

# Save data:
result_file = open('result.txt', 'w')
for line in result:
    result_file.write("{}\n".format(line))
result_file.close()
```

but I keep on getting the error message.
AttributeError: 'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'next'

Can someone tell me what I did wrong, is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you didn't intend to have literal hyphens/dashes in your file examples, can you edit (but preserve the four spaces in front of each line so whitespace/line feeds are retained). I assumed you didn't mean literal bullets which led to my edit.

Comment: It's `next(it)`, not `it.next()`

Comment: @JNevill I actually did intend to have literal dashes in the file examples, as I want to later on import the files into an outliner, which will recognized the dashes for blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files are iterators, so you can zip them:

```
with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2, open('result.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
        out.write(line1)
        out.write('  ')
        out.write(line2)
```

Comment: thanks for answering, my end goal is to create a third file with the merged output, how can I can get it with the "zip' method?

Comment: Thank you so much, the code beautifully written and works like a charm! I have one last question, if I want to add one string after line1(each line from file1), where should I put it ? I tried to concatenate by adding out.write(line1 + "added_string"), only to find that this added string will show up in front of line2 instead of at the end of line one,  don't know why that is the case.

Comment: @jarodise. Lines contain a newline. Do `print(line.rstrip(), suffix, sep='', file=out)`

Comment: is there an easier way for me to just add in the writing loop?

Comment: @jarodise. I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: I would like to add a text string " #card" to the end of line1(each line of file1), how can I do it while doing the zip?

Comment: @jarodise. Replace `out.write(line1)` with the `print` statement I mentioned earlier (with `line` -> `line1` and `suffix` -> `#card`).

Answer (score 1):

This is trivially done without python, like so:

```
paste -d'\n' file1.txt <(perl -pe '$_ = " $_"; ' file2.txt) > file3.txt

cat file3.txt
- one 
 - uno
- two 
 - dos
- three
 - tres
```

Here, [`paste`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html) is used to interleave the lines from the two files.

The Perl one-liner is used to prepend a blank to the lines from the second file. It uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: Your answer is functionally correct, but suggesting perl for a question that's asking about python seems funny.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Exactly! I posted the answer partly as a joke, and partly to help other users who may later have a similar question, but in a more language-agnostic way. Your answer is, of course, the best one for the OP, if they are looking for a pure Python solution.

Comment: Unless it's part of a larger program, your answer is the one I would prefer